# Pustefix - How to move .cache folder or disable page caching?

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a [Pustefix web application](http://pustefix-framework.org/index.html) based on [Pustefix' 0.16 tutorial](http://pustefix-framework.org/docs.html).

Initial setup went fine, basic web app works fine.

However, simple changes made in `txt/pages/main_EnterData.xml` (like changing color or some text labels) have no immediate effect and nothing happens either on `mvn clean tomcat:run`.

The culprit is easily identified: it is folder `webapp/.cache` containing cached web content; here EnterData.xml.

Folder `webapp/.cache` is generated by Pustefix's core servlet on startup. For yet unkown reasons, that cache folder is not updated if the input source file changed.

Question 1: How to configure Pustefix to automatically update its cache?
Question 2: How to configure Pustefix to disable each and every cache?
Question 3: How to tell Pustefix where the file cache should reside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for Q1:

Define environment variable MAKE_MODE and set it to some arbitrary answer but 'prod', i.e. like

```
% export MAKE_MODE=devel
% mvn tomcat:run
```

Things changed in Pustefix 0.19:

```
% mvn tomcat:run -Dpustefix.mode=devel
```

Alternatively, use context parameter 'mode' in web.xml like

```
   <context-param>
     <param-name>mode</param-name>
     <param-value>devel</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

Answer for Q3:
Run

```
% mvn tomcat:run-war
```

in order to run the unpacked war file. When doing so, `target/firstapp-myversion/.cache` becomes the new cache folder.

Answer for Q2:
Impossible without breaking Pustefix internals.